# I'm confused About Parameterized SQL vs Stored Procedures Having Dynamic SQL i.e. are they the same?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2015

I have created the following procedure:

```
 CREATE PROC dynamicColumnsWithCheck
 (
    @colName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @colCheck VARCHAR(MAX),
    @condition VARCHAR(MAX)
 )

 AS

 BEGIN

    DECLARE @sqlString NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sqlString = N'SELECT ' + @colName + ' FROM Student WHERE ' + @colCheck + ' = ''' + @condition + ''''

    EXEC sp_executesql @sqlString

 END
```

It works perfect for me but my question is that, Is this parameterized SQL?
or Is it the dangerous dynamic SQL?
I'm confused about the security of this procedure after searching and learning a bit about SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

It may be injected like:

```
  declare @sqlstring varchar(MAX)
  declare @colName varchar(500) = 'Password'
  declare @colCheck varchar(500) = 'StudentName' 
  declare @condition varchar(500) = 'Zeebo'' or ''''='''

  SET @sqlString = N'SELECT ' + @colName + ' FROM Student WHERE ' + @colCheck + ' = ''' + @condition + ''''


  PRINT (@sqlString)
```

Result:

> SELECT Password FROM Student WHERE StudentName = 'Zeebo' or ''=''

The `''=''` will always be valeted to be true, so it will return you everything, which will be disaster for user passwords.

So simple way to avoid SQL injection is to treat the user variable as a separate unit from the entire statement. For example, you could use `QuoteName` to wrap the user variable, so the dynamic part will be parsed as the input only, and will not affect the whole query.

For instance:

```
declare @sqlstring varchar(MAX)
      declare @colName varchar(500) = 'Password'
      declare @colCheck varchar(500) = 'StudentName' 
      declare @condition varchar(500) = 'Zeebo'' or ''''='''

      SET @sqlString = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@colName) + ' FROM Student WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@colCheck) + ' = ''' + QUOTENAME(@condition) + ''''
```

Back to use the previous injection method, the user input for @condition will be treated as a PURE string, not play any role in building the final @sqlString.
And the result will be:

> SELECT [Password] FROM Student WHERE [StudentName] = '[Zeebo' or
>   ''=']'

Which is not even a correct sql statement.

Comment: Oh! I just tried your injection and it worked
Thanks man that QUOTENAME worked.
but i tried this injection from c# text box but it didn't worked.
Is there a way?

Comment: Try use `Linq` as Dai suggested, the main ideas are the same. And testing the injection flaw may based on the error message you got.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this parameterized SQL? or Is it the dangerous dynamic SQL?

It's both.

SQL Server parameters can only be used to replace discrete **values** in queries - you cannot parameterise object identifiers (e.g. table names, column names) or clauses (e.g. `WHERE` predicates) which is why Dynamic SQL is still a thing.

Because of this problem, many people are turning to ORMs like Linq-to-Entities (Entity Framework) that safely generates SQL for you in a way that allows for the safe construction of queries defined at runtime.

It's far easier to change a `WHERE` clause in Linq than it is trying to generate your own SQL:

Try doing this query below by generating the SQL yourself - it will be a lot less readable, maintainable, and simply by generating SQL directly using concatenation you run the risk of injection vulnerabilities:

```
String GetUserName(String emailAddress) {

    IQueryable<User> query = database.Users;
    query = query.Where( u => u.Email == emailAddress );

    if( !userHasPermissionToViewAllUsers ) {
        query = query.Where( u => u.UserId == currentUserUserId );
    }

    return query.FirstOrDefault()?.UserName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro!
This stuff is awesome but I'm a bit beginner for it.
Anyway,  I'll give it a try.
And is there a good source for easy learning of LINQ?